# Show a larger image in a modal type window when a smaller image is clicked on using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on building a Portfolio for web development projects.  When you view a particular project it could have up to 10 screenshots.  These screenshots will always be smaller than I would like to show due to having to fit a description section next to the image as well as fitting this said description plus the image all within a 960pz wide div.

My solution I am wanting to try is to show a larger screenshot when the smaller screenshot image is clicked on.

The larger screenshot will load the image that will be defined in the Images `DATA`attribute for `data-big-img` soi the final markup for the image that is shown when the webpage loads looks like this...

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/FvJRySW.png" data-big-img="​http://i.imgur.com/FvJRySW.png" class="projectImgSmall" width="600" title="Click to View Full Size Image">
```

So here are some of my goals...

- Be able to load in 2 separate image files, I can make the click load in the same file or a completely different one, this is done by getting the image URL from my custom data attribute
- No matter the size of the larger image, it should be resized down so that the larger image is still viewable on the screen.  Now right now this means a tall image would likely have to be sized to make it look skinny because the popup modal/image is FIXED on the screen.  In reality though I would LOVE to instead just have a fixed width size and let the HEIGHT of the large image be AUTO....this would mean that instead of the FIXED overlay image I would need to somehow allow it to scroll down the page, I am liking this as I am thinking of it more.  Please help to do this if you can.
- Right now with the JS code I have come up with below, it does not always work good.  On some desktop screens it shows a large image centered however some images are not centered.  Also when viewed on Mobile type screen it shows the popup image as a tiny little image.
  I would really like for the large popup image to always be centered on the screen no matter the size of screen, as well as to always be a certain min-width and never over a max-width.  I think a percentage based width is the way to go here.
- Another issue, on my localhost server the image does change out as it loads the image from my Data attribute.  However when I ran this on a site like codePen or JSFiddle, it instead shows the IMG src is replaced with the new image when I view the source in DEV tools however on the screen it will show a broken image for some reason?
- Thats all I can think of at the moment....my code works on my dev server except the issues above.  Not always centering and not good on small screens.  IF I can change this to allow the large image to scroll down to see it that would be perfect and allow me to have a nice fixed width

The HTML...

```
<div id="projectOverlay"></div>
<div id="projectOverlayContent">
    <img id="projectImgBig" src="" alt="" width="400"  title="Click to close large image"/>
</div>
```

The JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(function() {

    // Show Large Project photo when smaller image is clicked on
    // <img class="projectImgSmall" width="200" src="150.png" data-big-img="big.png">
    $(".projectImgSmall").click(function(){
        var bigImg = $(this).data("big-img");
        var height = $( window ).height()-100;
        var width = $( window ).width()-200;


        //$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        $("#projectImgBig").attr("src",bigImg);
        $("#projectOverlay").show();
        $("#projectImgBig").css({
            'max-height': height,
            'max-width': width,
        });
        $("#projectOverlayContent").css({
            'max-height': height,
            'max-width': width,
            "position": "fixed",
             top:'50%',
             left:'50%',
             margin:'-'+(height / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+(width / 2)+'px'
        }).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#projectOverlayContent, #projectOverlay").click(function(){
        $("#projectImgBig").attr("src", "");
        $("#projectOverlay").hide();
        $("#projectOverlayContent").hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: Would each of the projects be listed on one page, and when clicked, bring the user to a new page dedicated to the project with the smaller thumbnails, descriptions and "hidden" larger images?

Comment: Have you had a look at the several (good) jQuery plugins out there that do similar things to what you want to achieve? (for example: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)